# Invert function with binary number

Tags: c, operators, logic, bit-manipulation, bit

Write a function invert(x,p,n) that returns x with the n bits that begin at position p inverted.  The code below is inverting digits from the end, but I need to change this code to inverting from beginning and I don't know how. I really don't understand logic operators and so.

function `invert()` should return this:

```
x = 123 (1111011)    
invert[x, 1, 2]  
x: 75 (1001011)
```

but it is returning this:

```
x = 123 (1111011)  
invert[x, 1, 2]  
x: 120 (1111000)
```

Current code:

```
unsigned int invert(unsigned int x, int p, int n)
{

    return x ^ ((~(~0<<n))<< (p-n));

}

int main()
{
int i, j, x, ii, nn;

scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &ii, &nn);

printf("x = %d ", x);
printf("(");
for (j = 0, i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (x & (1<<i))
    j = 1;
  if (j)
  {
    if (x & (1<<i))
      printf("1");
    else
      printf("0");
  }
}
printf(")\n");

printf("invert(x, %d, %d)\n", ii, nn);

x = invert(x, ii, nn);

printf("x: %d ", x);
printf("(");
for (j = 0, i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (x & (1<<i))
    j = 1;
  if (j)
  {
    if (x & (1<<i))
      printf("1");
    else
      printf("0");
  }
}
printf(")\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your desired bit numbering scheme isn't clear.  You give an example 8-bit number, and it _appears_ that you want to count the MSB (most significant bit) that is set as bit 0, and less significant bits counted as 1, 2, ... and your invert function should then return the value with the n bits starting at position p inverted?  What makes that tricky is the requirement to count from the most significant set bit.  Can you confirm that `invert(0x0FC3, 3,6) == 0x0E5B`?  See also [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: Did the solution provided work for you? Or maybe there are some problems with it? Also, were you able to find the error un the printing routine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#define BITS_IN_A_BYTE 8

unsigned int invert(unsigned int x, int p, int n)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int mask = 1;

    /* Puts at the end of mask as many 1s as indicated by n. */
    for (i = 1; i != n; i++) {
        mask = (mask << 1) + 1;
    }

    /* Moves the 1s to the position indicated by p. */
    mask = mask << ((BITS_IN_A_BYTE * sizeof(unsigned int) - p - n));

    return x ^ mask;
}
```

This will work if (as it seems reading your example) the most significant bit is considered as position 0. If you want to consider it as position 1, just write like this:

```
mask = mask << ((BITS_IN_A_BYTE * sizeof(unsigned int) - p - n + 1));
```

Also, this code isn't portable (it will work only on a architectures in which a byte is composed by eight bits), and it doesn't check for errors (for example, if the specified position is higher than the unsigned int dimension).

One more thing: testing this with your main function, the results were correct, but their binary representations were not. There must be something wrong with the conversion between decimal and binary in your main function.